# How to error handle TypeError with discord.py

Tags: error-handling, discord.py, typeerror

I'm learning how to create a discord bot with discord.py, and whenever I mess up my code, sometimes I get the "TypeError" error.

For example

```
@bot.command()
async def compress(ctx):
    directory = '/pictures/'
    picture = '83680009_p0.png'
    path = directory+picture
    img = Image.open(path)
    img.save(path, optimize=True, quality = 85)
    img.save()
```

There's a mistake in that code, and the mistake is in the line `directory = '/pictures/'`. There shouldn't be a backslash before `'pictures/'`. So, when I tried to run the compress command I got the error

```
TypeError: on_command_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'error'
```

Is there a way to handle the error and send a message with the bot whenever this error occurs? Thanks. Btw this is my first time asking a question so please tell me if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error said, your `on_command_error` is missing one argument. You haven't really provided the code for it but the proper way should be:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    ...
```

Also the error handler only handles discord.py errors, not `NameError`, `AttributeError`... To handle them you should use a simple try/except block.

Handling "normal" errors in the error handler

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    # If an error happens inside the command,
    # discord.py wraps it around with `commands.CommandInvokeError` 
    # which has the `original` attribute which is the "original" error
    error = getattr(error, "original", error)
    if isinstance(error, TypeError):
        ...
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        ...
    # And so on...
```

I wouldn't recommend this though, a command should be coded in such a way that it should never throw errors like these.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I accidentally  used `self` as an argument when it wasnt in a cog. Is there a way to handle `TypeError`, `NameError`, etc. like how discord.py errors and handled? I don't want to write a try /except block for each of my commands just because its probable that i put a bug in there.

Answer (score 0):

It says the function is missing one argument 'error'. To fix that:

```py
@bot.event
async def  on_command_error(ctx, error):
```

If you're inside a cog,

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I used `self` as an argument on the `on_command_error` function but i wasn't in a cog.

Comment: If it's not inside a class or a cog, don't add self.